system prompt repeats in the response after upgrading lanchain to 0.1.20
I'm Using llama3 8b model in my RAG architecture. Before upgrading lagchain model response are good. But after upgrading lanchain to 0.1.20 system prompts and context are getting repeated in the response.
Response Screenshot: https://i.sstatic.net/cW7ARCkg.png
Below is the prompt template im currently using.

B_INST, E_INST = "<|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>", "\n<|eot_id|>"
B_SYS, E_SYS = "<|begin_of_text|><|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>", "<|eot_id|>"
ASSISTANT_INST = "<|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>"

DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PROMPT = """\
You are a helpful, respectful and honest assistant. Always answer as helpfully as possible, while being safe. Your answers should not include any harmful, unethical, racist, sexist, toxic, dangerous, or illegal content. Please ensure that your responses are socially unbiased and positive in nature.

If a question does not make any sense, or is not factually coherent, explain why instead of answering something not correct. If you don't know the answer to a question, please don't share false information."""

def get_prompt_llama3(instruction, new_system_prompt=DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PROMPT ):
    SYSTEM_PROMPT = B_SYS + new_system_prompt + E_SYS
    prompt_template = SYSTEM_PROMPT + B_INST + instruction + ASSISTANT_INST
    return prompt_template

instruction = """\n\n CONTEXT:{context} \n Question:{question}\n"""

qa_template_llama3 = get_prompt_llama3(instruction)

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=qa_template_llama3,
                            input_variables=['question','context']) here

